What is the purpose of the %n and %t specifiers in the strftime function?
I was looking at the format specifiers and noticed that %n and %t were listed as valid specifiers. According to the documentation, the insert a new line and a horizontal tab character, respectively.
What is the reason for these specifiers when the \n and \t escape sequences exist, and is there any reason to use the format specifiers instead of the escape sequences?
Sample code:
strftime(buf, 64, "Day %e of %B in %Y%t(%D)%n", t);
printf("%s", buf);

strftime(buf, 64, "Day %e of %B in %Y\t(%D)\n", t);
printf("%s", buf);

Sample Output:
Day  8 of August in 2024    (08/08/24)
Day  8 of August in 2024    (08/08/24)



It allows the format string to be created at run-time, or read from some input source. When you use \t and \n the compiler will insert the tab and newline characters in the strings. With %t and %n they will be added at run-time.

This answer and %n format specifier program giving different outputs on different compilers. Why?

I disagree with closing: OP seems to have a question about %t and %n in strftime, not as %n in printf.

@YSC The dupes are correct afaik. The answer there explains that "It is predicated on the format string being controlled by user input."

Except that the %n format of printf() does not insert a newline at all. Even when enabled, it registers the number of bytes written by "this printf() call" in the given pointer argument --- Microsoft doc

This is unified with the Single UNIX Specification and date(1) command formats since C99. They don't use \n or \t because these sequences are shell escape sequences and if someone wants to pass a new line it would have to type \\n. Even more troubles are got if a format string is constructed in a variable. %n and %t make it more convenient and consistent - when you know date(1), you don't need to recall differences.

I think this is because strftime() is often used with a runtime format string (since unlike printf it's possible to implement it in a way that doesn't break on invalid format strings).
E.g. the clock app in XFCE lets me specify a custom datetime format string in this format.
Supporting %n,%t directly in strftime means the application developers don't have to manually parse escape sequences if they don't need anything other than linefeed/tab.

strftime

Copies into ptr the content of format, expanding its format specifiers into the corresponding values that represent the time described in timeptr, with a limit of maxsize characters.


%n    New-line character ('\n')
%t    Horizontal-tab character ('\t')

They have the same inherent meaning, which prompted you to as the question. However, they have a fundamental difference. When you know where you want to use your \n and \t when you write your code, they will be written by the compiler and will spare you the time of writing them at runtime.
However, one may wonder, what's the difference between adding %n at runtime and adding \n at runtime, after all, you can generate your string as well.
The key difference is that with \n you are hard-coding the newline and with \t you are hard-coding the tabulation, whereas, with %n and %t respectively you delegate this task to the function.
So it ultimately boils down to the question of whether you want this function to do this job or not. Imagine a case when in a future version the function will be able to add a <br> instead of a \n in the right context and will do the correct replacement. If you use %n now, then you subscribe for future benefits of this function, if it adds some new benefits that did not necessarily exist at the time of your writing the code. Yet, if you know for sure that \n will be the character and it will never change, then it's better to do this job at compile-time.
Also, \n is only simple when you do not have to escape the \. Once you start to have to escape it and repeatedly so, then it can grow to things like \\\\\\\\n or so :)
